# Speeding up data.table SD[,]

Tags: r, data.table

I have code that use the below snippet a fair bit as i want the most recent record after grouping by groups group1, group2, group3 and group4

```
dt[order(-date), .SD[1,], by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)]
```

The issue is the code is extremely slow. Is there a faster alternative?

Comment: Do you have the development version installed? If I remember correctly, `.SD[1L]` has recently been optimized so there may be a speed improvement just from updating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `head` would improve the speed.

```
dt[order(-date), head(.SD, 1), by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)]
```

Or another option is `.I` that can speed up the process significantly

```
dt[dt[order(-date), .I[1L], by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)]$V1]
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(234)
dt <- data.table(group1 = sample(letters, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
              group2 = sample(letters, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
              group3 = sample(1:10, 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
              group4 = sample(5:15, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
              date = sample(1:30, 1e6, replace=TRUE), 
              value = rnorm(1e6))
system.time(dt[order(-date), .SD[1,], by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  29.63   15.65   46.17 

 system.time(dt[order(-date), head(.SD, 1), by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)])
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  0.22    0.00    0.14 
 system.time(dt[dt[order(-date), .I[1L], by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)]$V1])
 #  user  system elapsed 
 #  0.23    0.02    0.15
```

Also, from @Frank's suggestion

```
system.time(dt[order(-date), .SD[1L], by=.(group1, group2, group3, group4)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.16    0.05    0.16
```

Comment: Switching from `.SD[1,]` to `.SD[1L]` or `.SD[1]` is also fast, as noted here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735 (not sure if devel version is needed). If I remember correctly, `unique` (another option here) is slower.

Comment: Thanks akrun. That worked. And thanks for your suggestions also Frank